# Bulk GET in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm building an application using Django and Django REST Framework. I'm reasonably comfortable with base Django but I'm very much a newbie with DRF. Hoping someone can help me with the below.

I have a list of dictionaries that want to send via my API as a single call, rather than sequentially sending `request.get` calls in, say, a loop (tediously slow, too many database hits etc.)

I've built a list and serialised it to JSON which now looks something like:

```
[
   {
      "kingdom":"Plantae",
      "phylum":"Tracheophyta",
      "class_taxonomic":"Magnoliopsida",
      "order":"Apiales",
      "family":"Apiaceae",
      "genus":"Heracleum",
      "species":"mantegazzianum",
      "taxon_rank":"SPECIES"
   },
   {
      "kingdom":"Plantae",
      "phylum":"Bryophyta",
      "class_taxonomic":"Bryopsida",
      "order":"Orthotrichales",
      "family":"Orthotrichaceae",
      "genus":"Zygodon",
      "species":"viridissimus",
      "taxon_rank":"SPECIES"
   },
   {
      "kingdom":"Plantae",
      "phylum":"Tracheophyta",
      "class_taxonomic":"Magnoliopsida",
      "order":"Caryophyllales",
      "family":"Polygonaceae",
      "genus":"Fallopia",
      "species":"japonica",
      "taxon_rank":"SPECIES"
   }
]
```

Is it possible to send this list to my model (`taxonData`) and return those model instances if they're present in the above list? If so, what would be the best way to achieve this? Would I need to use `generics.ListAPIView` and a custom `get_queryset` method? If I try this with the following code:

```
# models.py

class TaxonData(models.Model):
    kingdom = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    phylum = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    class_taxonomic = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    family = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    genus = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    species = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    taxon_rank = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (( "kingdom", "phylum", "class_taxonomic",
            "order", "family", "genus", "species"),)

# serializers.py
class taxonDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TaxonData
        fields = '__all__'

# views.py
class taxonDataListViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class=taxonDataSerializer
```

I get an error in the console saying:

```
AttributeError: type object 'taxonDataListViewSet' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'
```

I have to admit to being a little lost in the DRF documentation, I can't see a way through at the moment.

Comment: Hi, try to add `queryset = TaxonData.objects` parameter in your `taxonDataListViewSet` class first.

Comment: Are you using a router?

Answer (score 0):

Import APIView from rest_framework.views in your views.py.
Create a post request and pass this list as data.
iterate your data and make the response.
here's the way how you can do it.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
class TaxonDataAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = self.request.data
        response = {}
        for row in data:
          try:
            obj = TaxonData.objects.get(kingdom=row['kingdom'], phylum=row['phylum'], class_taxonomic=row['class_taxonomic'], order=row['order'], family=row['family'], genus=row['genus'], species=row['species'], taxon_rank=row['taxon_rank'])
            # do whatever you want to do with this obj and make the response
          except:
            # do what you want if the list item does not exist in database
        return Response(response)
```